# Assert Request URL is specified URL using Protractor

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

Does Protractor provide a native way to check requests going out from events such as a button click?

For example, `onClick()`, a POST request is made to `https://myapi.net/customers` and I'd like to, during my test, make an assertion on the `Request URL`.

I've seen some `npm` packages that might be provide some help, but looking through the Protractor API's, I can't seem to find anything that would handle this out of the box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do is to use **browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()**

Preceding approach will provide the current url on browser but if you are interested in url which is triggered after click button then i am not aware how we deal this in webdriverJs but in .Net there is Support.Event namespace which provide the way to do action after  ElementClicked event.

[image: Selenium Events support]